# Cannot access element shown by v-if in component mounted callback

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

```
<template>
<div>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">

      <div class="ui active inline loader" v-if="loading" key="loading"></div>
      <div v-else key="loaded">
          <span class="foo" ref="foo">the content I'm after is here</span>
      </div>

    </transition>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                loaded: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            setTimeout(() => {  // simulate async operation
                this.loaded = true
                console.log($(this.$refs.foo).length, $(this.$el.find('.foo')).length)
            }, 2000)
        },
    }
</script>
```

Regardless if I use `this.$refs` or `this.$el`, I'm only able to access the loader div (`<div class="ui active inline loader"/>`).

How am I supposed to access an element which doesn't exist when the component is mounted? Do I have to change `v-if` to `v-show`?

Comment: Seems like you should be `watch`ing `loading`.

Comment: @RoyJ Hmm, how would that make a difference from executing the code after `loading` is altered as above?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If `loading` is `true`, there is no `foo` element to access. Is there a reason that the content is in your template rather than in your viewmodel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vue renders to the DOM [asynchronously](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue). So, even though you are setting your loaded property to `true`, the `ref` will not exist until the next tick in Vue's cycle.

To handle that, use the [`$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) method.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    loading: true
  },
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.loading = false
      this.$nextTick(() => console.log(this.$refs.done))
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="loading">Loading</div>
  <div ref="done" v-else>Done</div>
</div>
```

Additionally, in the question, the `v-if` expression is `loading` which will always be undefined because the data property is called `loaded`.