# vuejs mounted is called even if component was not loaded via v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vuejs for my app look like this

app.vue

```
<template>
<div>
 <custom-elem v-if="somefalseCondition"> </custom-elem>
</div>
</template>
```

CustomElem.vue

```
<template>
  some code
 </template>
<script> 
export default {
 mounted(){
  console.log('demo')
}
}
</script>
```

I am expecting this mounted should be called when element is actually rendered on screen , but it is executing even after condition inside v-if is false , what am i missing here ?

Comment: You might use `setTimeout` in mounted https://stackoverflow.com/a/46041731/13338936

Answer (score 5):

That is not correct, there must be a mistake somewhere.

v-if="false" avoid the creation of the component instance.

No event (beforeCreate, created, mounted...) is triggered if v-if is allways falsy.

Are you sure that your condition is allways falsy?
This must be the case since the beginning of your parent component, be careful about changing values, if any data passing inside your condition is not falsey at some point of time, component will be instanciated and events raised.

Regards

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had :v-if by accident instead of v-if. So it was always true.

Comment: I know this question has some time, but I wanted to follow this up because I have the same issue and I've hardcoded v-if to be always false -no colons before. You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cmk8n27o/. Just a heads-up that mounted may run even if v-if=false.

Comment: @javag87 your jsfiddle is correctly showing the mounted message because it's the mounted method of the root component (which is always loaded), if you've had a child component that you are rendering with v-if then it will only execute mounted when v-if is true

Comment: Like said in this post, pay attention at some default value being instantly updated with from an async call for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of using **mounted()** the lifecycle hook you are looking for is **created()**. if you use `console.log()` in `created()`, it'll not be called.

Comment: Events beforeCreate, created or mounted are called after v-if goes true only.

Comment: @Slim since **mounted()** is used and <custom-elem> is used in parent component(app.vue). it will be available in DOM. so it gets called :p.

Comment: @HOLLAMUKUNDA we disagree. if "somefalseCondition" is false, as its name suggests, no component is created. Please inspect this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XONqRG

Answer (score 1):

Well according to documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) , It reads

> Called after the instance has been mounted, where el is replaced by
> the newly created vm.$el. If the root instance is mounted to an
> in-document element, vm.$el will also be in-document when mounted is
> called.

Note that where it says where **instance** is mounted and not when template is rendered, which basically means as your component is called the component class will be loaded and mounted hook will be called. It makes sense because when your `v-if` becomes true, merely its template will be added and actual component class will not be loaded

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this, even if you outsource it to a portal. Everything you do in the mounted hook of the component, is actually "doing his job." You simply don't see it until the template is rendered. One way to fix this is to place the function you run in the mounted hook inside the if() condition itself.

For example, I had the function that called e.preventDefault on the mousemove event, even though the component was in v-if and wasn't rendered, it still messed up my input range slider, I couldn't drag it as expected.